# how can i create repeating section in sharepoint site?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

In my sharepoint site I have a section that need repeat 'n' time.

This section get information from a list.

Now I want get number of rows from list and repeat my section for each row.

I can get Data and number of list's row but I can't repeat my section.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is Viusal Web Part / Visual Studio an option? Through XSLT you can achieve though, but I find it dirty :)

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri why dirty? This is one of the thing the XSLT is perfect for

Comment: Well if its reusable / clean (don't need SharePoint Designer).. I'm okay with it :)